# Xtend build fails, with java containing invalid characters

Tags: java, xtend

All of a sudden, the Java classes being generated by Xtend seem to contain invalid syntax.

eg:

```
public Long getEntityId() {
    return ??field.simpleName??;
}
```

where previously the syntax was generated correctly:

```
public Long getEntityId() {
    return entityId;
}
```

I haven't changed anything related to this class, or the processor - I've simply done an update from my source control.

Answer (score 3):

This is caused by the encoding on the Xtend class being set to ASCII, rather than UTF-8 within the IDE.

As a result, the following code (shown in UTF-8 encoding)

```
body = ['''
    return «field.simpleName»;'''
```

becomes the following (shown in ASCII encoding

```
body = ['''
    return ��field.simpleName��;''']
```

Ensure the project's default is set to UTF-8:

[image: Set eclipse default to UTF-8]